# Infinite scroll does not working on mobile

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web-app and I have this function for infinite scrolling on page:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
  let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  if (bottomOfWindow) {
    //dostuff
  }
}
```

It works perfectly on my computer (Chrome) but not on my phone (Chrome too).